# Max length of meta_value

Tags: custom-field, meta-value

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the max length of the `meta_value` field for posts and user meta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both `usermeta.meta_value` and `postmeta.meta_value` are stored as LONGTEXT. Here's how the MySQL docs describe the size of a LONGTEXT data type:

> "A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (2<sup>32</sup> – 1)
>   characters. The effective maximum length is less if the value contains
>   multi-byte characters. The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT
>   columns also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the
>   client/server protocol and available memory."

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html)

Comment: It suffices to say that it would take a lot of text to max your limit.